# Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

This question is about Windows Workflow Foundation. I am working with Windows Workflow Foundation 4.5 hosted in a MVC Web application.
I have a requirement where user would like to ‘approve’ (resume bookmarks) multiple instances of requests in a ‘batch’ with all or nothing approach. Meaning they would like to roll back the workflow instances in the batch to previous state if any on the instance encountered exception while being resumed. 
Currently I am just naively looping through each instance in the batch and calling resume bookmark. It works somewhat until it does not. We are seeing some issues where one of the instance in the batch failed due to some exception.
I have searched everywhere and could not find any useful information. I was hoping you could have some insight to it.
Would there be a way to wrap the entire loop within ‘TransactionSope’?